# How to define numbers format in Flex (lexical analyzer)?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

What I need :

Acceptable  > `1234` & `12.34`

Error (Non acceptable) > `12.34.56`

Scanner.L :

```
      ...
%%

[0-9]+                printf("Number ");
[0-9]+"."[0-9]+       printf("Decimal_Number ");
"."                   printf("Dot "):

%%
      ...
```

After compile & run :

```
Input :
1234    12.34    12.34.65

Output :
Number    Decimal_Number      Decimal_Number Dot Number
```

How to print `Error` instead of `Decimal_Number Dot Number` (Or just ignore it) ?

<s>Is it possible to define `space` before & after number as seperator ?</s>

Comment: Do you really need to? `12.34.56` is (presumably) going to be a syntax error anyway, so does it really matter that it's not a lexical error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often considered better to detect errors like `12.34.56` in your parser rather than your scanner. But there is also an argument that you can produce  better error messages by detecting the error lexically.

If you want to do so, you can use two patterns; the first one detects only correct numbers and the second one detects a larger set of strings, including all the erroneous strings (but not anything which could be legitimate). This relies on the matching behaviour of (f)lex: it always accepts the longest match, and if the longest token is matched by two or more rules, it uses the first matching rule.

For example, suppose you wanted to accept dots by themselves as `'.'`, numbers as `NUMBER` tokens, and produce an error on numeric strings with more than one dot. You could do that with three rules:

```
  /* If the token is just a dot, match it here */
\.                             { return '.';    }
  /* Match integers without decimal points */
[[:digit:]]+                   { return INTEGER; }
  /* If the token is a number including a decimal point,
   * match it here. This pattern will also match just '.',
   * but the previous rules will be preferred.) */
[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*     { return FLOAT; }
  /* This rule matches any sequence of dots and digits.
   * That will also match single dots and correct numbers, but
   * again, the previous rules are preferred. */
[.[:digit:]]+                  { /* signal error */
                                 return BADNUMBER; }
```

You need to be very careful with solutions like the above. For example, the last rule will match `..` and `...`, which might be valid tokens (or even valid sequences of `.` tokens.)

Suppose, for example, that your language permits "range" expressions like `4 .. 17` (meaning the list of integers from 4 to 17, or some such). Your users might expect `4..17` to be accepted as a range expression, but the above will produce a BADNUMBER error, even when you add the rule

```
".."                           { return RANGE; }
```

at the beginning, because `4..` will match `BADNUMBER` at a previous point in the scan.

In order to avoid false alerts, we need to modify the BADNUMBER rule to avoid matching strings which include two (or more) consecutive dots. And we also need to make sure that `4..17` is not lexed as `4.` followed by `.17`. (This second problem could be avoided by insisting that `.` neither start not end a numeric token, but that might annoy some users.)

So, we start with the actual dot tokens:

```
"."                            { return '.'; }
".."                           { return RANGE; }
"..."                          { return ELLIPSIS; }
```

To avoid overmatching a number followed by `..`, we can use flex's trailing context operator. Here, we recognize a sequence of digits terminated by a `.` as a number only if the string is followed by something other than a `.`:

```
[[:digit:]]+                   { return INTEGER; }
  /* Change * to + so that we don't do numbers ending with . */
[[:digit:]]*(\.[[:digit:]]+)?  { return FLOAT; }
  /* Numbers which end with dot not followed by dot */
[[:digit:]]+\./[^.]            { return FLOAT; }
```

Now we need to fix the error rule. First, we limit it to recognizing strings where every dot is followed by a digit. Then, similar to the above, we do match the case where there is a trailing dot not followed by another dot:

```
[[:digit:]]*(\.[[:digit:]]+)+  { return BADNUMBER; }
[[:digit:]]*(\.[[:digit:]]+)+\./[^.] { return BADNUMBER; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the duty of the lexer, but of the parser (yacc or bison). If you define `.` as a valid symbol then there is no surprise that

```
12.34.56
```

is tokenized as

```
Decimal_Number Dot Number
```

The point is that the parser won't have a rule that accepts that sequence of token so the error will be raised later. White space is usually ignored so forcing a space between numbers won't make sense, especially in a context where you could have `12.34+56.78` that won't be tokenized as `Decimal_Number Binary_Operator Decimal_Number` because it lacks white space.

Comment: So there isn't a way to do what I said just in Flex ? Maybe remove `.` definition or something ?

Comment: Your question is an XY problem, if you really want you can force white space inside tokens as much as you want (eg. `[0-9]+"."[0-9]+" "`) but it's wrong and shouldn't be considered at all.

Comment: No, ignore that white space thing. Is there a way to return error or just ignore `12.34.56` format in Flex?

Answer (score 1):

You can check my procedure to handle your problem. But as you are trying with `lex` you should know that whenever it matches any case then it work.
Now change as like as follows:

```
%%

[0-9]+                {printf("Number ");}
[0-9]+[.][0-9]*[.]+[0-9|.]*       {printf("error ");}
[0-9]+[.][0-9]+       {printf("Decimal_Number ");}
%%
```

Now the program works as you want.

```
Input :
1234    12.34    12.34.65

Output :
Number    Decimal_Number     Error
```

Comment: In `[0-9|.]` the `|` is just another character, so that will match a literal `|`.

Comment: @Md Shibbir Hossen - Exactly what I wanted to, Thank you very much
I added `"."               {printf("Dot");}`, woks without any problem.

Comment: no this is `or` here may `0-9` or `.` not character `|`

Comment: It's inside a character class, so no, it is not `or`. It's just another character. If you want to write "a digit or .", you write `[0-9.]`.